# What is common practice for adding supplements to IEEE Journal papers?

Tags: publications, ieee, supporting-information

I am completely new to publishing with IEEE and I'm confused about handling of supplementary material. The way I know this from ACM is you are able to provide, e.g., a ZIP file with additional data, code, etc. that the reader can simply download along the paper from the digital library.

I've got an IEEE Sensors paper that is accepted with minor changes and one issue I have is that I've got some tables in an Excel spreadsheet that I uploaded for reviews as "supporting document" on manuscriptcentral.org. I realized that the content was printed into the proof PDF in a very odd and unfavorable manner, but didn't give it much thought. However, a reviewer commented that the data is no readable and I should take care of proper formatting of the tables. Due to unclear instructions, I am not sure if the reviewers actually received the XLSX for review, or if they only got the PDF. Anyways, for the final paper I obviously don't want this in the camera ready version like that, I want to provide the spreadsheet as a separate file. I tried uploading it using a ZIP archive as a container, but apparently, at manuscriptcentral.org this file type is not allowed.

So I guess, my question is: for the final paper, will there be a way to upload supplementary material that will be posted along my paper at IEEExplore? I was under that impression from what I read at the [IEEE Author Center](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/prepare-supplementary-materials/) page. There, some "recommended file formats" are listed, but nowhere does it say I cannot provide other types of data. Apart from that, I am not able to find much on the topic. I would like to add that I am aware of IEEE DataPort, but this would be way too excessive for the few tables I'm providing along the paper.

Could somebody clarify? What would be the best procedure in this case?

Comment: These seem like questions for the handling editor. I don't publish in IEEE but I don't think these things are nearly that standard across their journals.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try to contact the editor but got no response. I also sent an e-mail to the admin, but I'm now trying to reach out to other people since time is running and I think these things are probably common knowledge within the community. At ACM, for example, I more or less know how things are done, but here I'm a bit lost. I suppose folks more familiar with IEEE processes may be able to help.

Comment: I don't think they actually are common knowledge; what you have is a communication problem between you and the journal, that is: you intend for your data supplement to accompany the article in a spreadsheet format, they're trying to attach it in some ugly table format for the document. You need to know if this is just an oddity of the review system or if something needs to be done differently for the final version. You can only resolve that with the journal. This is not something for you to wrestle with the submission software over, it's something to communicate with the journal staff about.